# How to calculate time difference from different tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have two tables. I want to calculate the year difference.
This is table "lulus":

[image]

and this is table "mahasiswa"

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I have marked Tanggal Lulus and Tahun Masuk and I want to calculate **"TahunMasuk - TahunLulus"**. Are there any ways to calculate them eventhough **TahunMasuk** only have the year?

Comment: What columns do you plan to use to join these two tables together?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: No, I don't think you want to _join_ using these columns.

Comment: I plan to use NIM column to join the tables together @TimBiegeleisen and I'm using MySQL Workbench

Comment: are there any ways to join them? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
SELECT m.TahunMasuk - YEAR(l.TahunLulus) 
   FROM lulus l left join mahasiswa m on l.MahasiswaId = m.MahasiswaId
```

You should adapt the query to your needs since I don't know what are the fields on which to join those two tables. I have just made an assumption.

Comment: yes you're right. I use MahasiswaID to join the tables. But, when I tried it the result came like this "Unknown column TahunMasuk in fieldlist"

Comment: I updated a little bit the query, Can you try to do select all.  SELECT *
   FROM lulus l left join mahasiswa m on l.MahasiswaId = m.MahasiswaId. In order to see if column names and join works. Maybe there are some typos in column names

Comment: yeah it works. Thank you for helping. God Bless You :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This :

```
SELECT Column1,Column2,DATEPART(YYYY,A.TahunMasuk)-B.TahunLulus FROM Table1 A JOIN Table2 B ON A.Id=B.Id
```